# Changing css style with java

Tags: java, javascript, css

Is there a way to change the css style(defined in the page source) dynamically with Java? I know it is possible to do it with JavaScript. If there isn't, are there other situations where JavaScript is the only choice developing a web app?

Comment: Are you talking about a Java applet, a servlet, or what?

Comment: About a JSP page to be specific.

Comment: I'm confused by this question, as JS is client side, and JAVA (unless an applet) would be server side.. no?  You can do anything you like server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew is right. The question should be specified better.

If you are about applet that is running on current page your can call any javascript including javascript code that changes style of any element.

You just have to add attribute mayscript to applet tag and then use code like the following:
JSObject win = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(this);
win.eval("documeent.getElementById('myelem').style='border-color: red'");

If you are asking about sevlet/jsp you can
1. generate full html code including css
2. bind style element to URL that is mapped to servlet or JSP that generates CSS.

where styles URL brings us to servlet that generates css dynamically using parameter "id".

I hope it helps. Otherwise please try to specify you question.

Comment: I guess it helps, not sure about syntax for binding the style element to a URL, and dynamically generating css, are there real-world examples out there by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use JS in the JSP page like you would in a regular HTML page?